# How to attach filled Sqlite DB to App with Kotlin and android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

I have an Offline application that uses Sqlite and Room. Also I have filled the DB and want to attach it to my application in Android Studio.

My question is: How? Can I do that? if yes, is that acceptable or I have to connect to internet and use Retrofit at least for one time and get data from Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/prepopulate

> To prepopulate a Room database from a prepackaged database file that is located anywhere in your app's assets/ directory, call the createFromAsset() method from your RoomDatabase.Builder object before calling build():

```kotlin
Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "Sample.db")
    .createFromAsset("database/myapp.db")
    .build()
```

> The createFromAsset() method accepts a string argument that contains a relative path from the assets/ directory to the prepackaged database file.

Comment: You can also find a good tutorial about that here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pe28WeQ0VCc&ab_channel=Stevdza-San